# UICollectionViewCell not correct size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my Storyboard it looks like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY11v.png)

But when running the project it looks like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osdeC.png)

I am not using "Use Auto Layout". I think this happen when I accidentally pressed the "Use Auto Layout" to tick it on. I pressed it again to tick it off, and now it looks like that.

Any suggestions what may be wrong?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to set the Autoresizing in the Size Inspector again:

[image]

Comment: @KimPhoe No problem. Glad i helped you out! :-)